# nginx responding to unknown host names?

Tags: nginx, http, https

I have two domains that point to the same server, one we'll call `home` and one we'll call `web`.

I'm running nginx on port 80 for HTTP and 443 for HTTPS. In my server definitions, I've defined two servers:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name web;
    # ...
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name web;
    # ...
}
```

In practice, it works just fine. However, when I try accessing `home`, which points to the same IP address as `web`, I get served `web` rather than getting a 404 or the like.

How can I configure nginx to 404 requests that don't match a server name? Do I need to define a default server which just bounces things down to 404s?

Answer (score 19):

For http:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 404;
}
```

For https, you actually need to point nginx at ssl cert/key. According to
[documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html), nginx only looks at 'Host' header and does not look at TLS SNI when matching server_name. This means that nginx must be able to accept/decrypt ssl connection before it can inspect the Host header.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    server_name _;
    ssl_certificate <path to cert>
    ssl_certificate_key <path to key>
    return 404;
}
```

The cert/key can be any cert/key e.g. self-signed.

If cert/key are not specified, nginx still tries to use such default_server and fails as it can't accept ssl connection.

Answer (score 6):

The Catchall server block also needs a `server_name` that you need to set to an invalid value like `_`. This way, the server block will not match any other hostname and will just be used as last resort. The config will look like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name _;

    return 404;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, on the embedded system that I'm using, this doesn't work and I don't have a way of getting the logs. Upvoting, but unable to verify that this works.

Answer (score 4):

The first server {} in your config is like a catch-all so that is why it is being shown. Add something like this before the listen 80 server {}

```
server {
    return 404;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name web;
    # ...
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name web;
    # ...
}
```

Comment: Great, but it appears that HTTPS requests still get forwarded to the wrong place. I have SNI compiled into nginx, is there a way to do the same thing for unmatched HTTPS requests?

Comment: add another for the listen 443 then

Comment: If I add a `server { listen 443 default_server; return 404; }`, my other SSL virtual hosts are broken.

Comment: See my reply - need to specify cert/key because nginx looks at Host header (rather than SNI) for server matching. If cert/key are not specified, nginx still tries to use such default_server and fails as it can't accept ssl connection.