# Nginx catch-all ssl block with return invalidates all other ssl hosts

Tags: nginx, ssl

I recently tried to set up the following server block:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl default_server; # this and
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server; # this

    server_name _;

    return 404;
}
```

This works perfectly for `http` connections. But every connection to other ssl hosts fails if I activate this block. Chrome for example outputs `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`. If I comment-out the lines marked with #this, then it works again. In my opinion, this seems to be a bug. Another user has stated the same problem in a comment in [this post](https://serverfault.com/a/559097/141849).

Comment: I can't get it. You mean that if you activate this block, you get error on any other valid server name?

Comment: Yes, exactly this behavior happens.