# Convince nginx to terminate the connection if none of my virtual host matches the server name sent by the client?

Tags: nginx

I'm painfully aware that using the ssl equivalent of:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        return 444;
}
```

[kills all ssl exchanges](https://serverfault.com/a/593668/180142), meanwhile, without something of the sort, nginx happily serve a random virtual host. Instead of trying to gracefully end the connection, I would like nginx to simply terminate the tcp connection. If I'm not mistaken, the ssl has to [send the domain as part of the negotiation.](https://journal.paul.querna.org/articles/2005/04/24/tls-server-name-indication/) I would like nginx to simply close the connection if it can't find a virtual host that matches the domain the client is asking for. How could I do this? Should I use a middleman?

If a correct domain is give:

```
1. C: (TLS Handshake) Hello, I support XYZ Encryption, and I am trying to connect to 'site.example.com'.
2. S: (TLS Handshake) Hi There, Here is my Public Certificate, and lets use this encryption algorithm.
```

Now an invalid one:

```
1. C: (TLS Handshake) Hello, I support XYZ Encryption, and I am trying to connect to 'invalid-domain.com'.
2. S: CLOSE
```

Comment: You can't do that. The TLS handshake happens in OpenSSL and is complete before nginx gets a chance to do anything.

Comment: @MichaelHampton would a middle man, like haproxy, be able to improve this? Or all ssl servers treat openssl as a blackbox?

Comment: It pretty much IS a black box. And not one you want to go messing around with for trivial reasons. Crypto is very easy to screw up.