# Nginx doesn’t listen to HTTPS requests for subdomains

Tags: nginx, subdomain

I have a Nginx server that is hosting both the main domain `foo.com` and a subdomain `bar.foo.com` for a website. I only have a certificate for my main domain, so I only want HTTP requests for the subdomain. I have configured both server blocks, and all requests work well: `http://foo.com` will be redirected to `https://foo.com`, and `http://bar.foo.com` just stays on HTTP.

However, a problem rises when I tried to connect `https://bar.foo.com`, although I have not configured the subdomain server block to listen for 443 or ssl requests, the request is still handled, and after getting a warning from the browser that the certificate has a different host name than the one I am requesting, the page I get is from the main domain `foo.com`.

So, apparently, the `server` block that was supposed to only listen to HTTPS requests of my main domain, somehow is also listening to HTTPS requests of the subdomain, I don't want this to happen.

Here is my configuration for the main domain:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  foo.com www.foo.com;

  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen       443 ssl;
  server_name  foo.com www.foo.com;

  ssl                  on;
  ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/cert/foo.com.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/cert/foo.com.key;
  ...

  location / {
    root   /var/www/foo.com/public_html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
  }
}
```

Here is my configuration for the subdomain:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  bar.foo.com www.bar.foo.com;

  location / {
    root   /var/www/bar.foo.com/public_html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
  }
}
```

And here is a snippet of the Nginx configuration file:

```
server {
  listen       80 default_server;
  listen       [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name  _;
  root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

  location / {
}
```

I have tried deleting `foo.com` after `listen` in the 443 server block of my main domain, but it doesn't help.

I would like Nginx either not listen to requests such as `https://bar.foo.com` or to simply return 404 or 444.

Comment: Configure a default server to `return 444` for unmatched SSL certificate names. This answer contains more details: https://serverfault.com/q/373929/131019 This relies on your visitors implementing SNI, which you can [mostly rely on these days](https://caniuse.com/#feat=sni).

Comment: @CosmicOssifrage Sorry, I am new to Nginx, may you tell me exactly how to configure such server? I have looked at the answer you provided but are still confused. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does the file really end with `.conf`. Just curious, because it seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the solution. Just like @Tero and @Cosmic correctly pointed out, my only 443 `server` block for the main domain is being set to the default `server` block for all 443 requests.

I commented the `server` block in the Nginx configuration file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and added the following two `server` blocks:

```
server {
  listen      80 default_server;
  server_name  _;
  return 444;
}

server {
  listen       443 ssl default_server;
  server_name  _;
  ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/cert/foo.bar.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/cert/foo.bar.key;
  return 444;
}
```

The first one will be set to the default `server` block for any HTTP requests, dropping any unmatched requests, and similarly the second one will drop any unmatched 443 or HTTPS requests.

The solution that @Tero provided won't work, because Nginx expects a certificate for any SSL `server` blocks, so you will need to provide it with a certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have only one `server` block configured for port 443, it is the default virtual server used by nginx to service all requests to port 443.

To add a default server for port 443 (TLS), you can add the following virtual host:

```
server {
    listen 443 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 444;
}
```